# msgraph subscrition to 1:1 or group chat messages from Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to create an [MS graph subscription ("change tracking")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-beta) to receive notifications when a user messages a Teams bot installed in their personal context. The following registration is accepted by the API (and can later be retireved with `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions`). Note that this registration has be posted to the beta version of the API:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{                                             
       "changeType": "created,updated",
       "notificationUrl": "EventHub:<kv-secret-uri>?tenantId=<tenant-uuid>",
       "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "EventHub:<kv-secret-uri>?tenantId=<tenant-uuid>",
       "resource": "appCatalogs/teamsApps/<installed-app-id>/installedToChats/getAllMessages",
       "expirationDateTime":"2023-10-19T12:00:00.000000Z",
       "clientState": "secretClientValue",
    }' https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
```

However, when sending 1:1 messages to the bot, no events are posted to the EventHub. Am I not supposed to receive notifications for 1:1 messages this way?

Alternatively, I am able to subscribe to `chats/<chat-id>/messages` and receive updates this way, but how do I find the `<chat-id>` of all users that installed the app? One might have imagined that `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps/<installed-app-id>/installedToChats` would give this information, but that endpoint seems not to be implemented, nor does subscription to `appCatalogs/teamsApps/<installed-app-id>/installedToChats` yield any change events when a user adds the bot to their personal context.

Relevant parts of my `manifest.json`. The bot is installed to a specific organization.

```
"bots": [
  {
    "botId": "<external-app-id>",
    "scopes": ["team","personal"],
    "supportsFiles": false,
    "isNotificationOnly": false,
    "commandLists": []
  }
],
...
"authorization": {
  "permissions": {
    "resourceSpecific": [
      {
        "type": "Application",
        "name": "ChannelMessage.Read.Group"
      },
      {
        "type": "Application",
        "name": "ChatMessage.Read.Chat"
      },
      {
        "type": "Application",
        "name": "ChatMessage.Send.Chat"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The service principal has the following API permissions: AppCatalog.Read.All, Chat.ReadWrite.WhereInstalled, Chat.Read.All, ChatMessage.Read.All. (The latter two are not desirable, but are added in order to minimize the risk of permissions errors.)

Can anyone give me a hint as to how to use the MS graph API to be evented on 1:1 chat messages from users?

Comment: You can retrieve the chatId for a user who has installed your app using below graph API.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/teamwork/installedApps/{teamsAppInstallationId}/chat

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-v1.0&tabs=http&preserve-view=true

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT That solves half the problem, but the question is which users to check for? It would probably be feasible in my use case to maintain subscriptions for the users that actually want to use the app, but the AD in question may still have thousands of users. Plus, it is not ideal for the app to have permission to iterate users.

Comment: Bittrance - Whenever user install the app, you can store user context somewhere in storage and utilize that later for further actions using oninstallation event.

Comment: @chetansharma-msft Indeed. It is a bit unsatisfying to have to rely on install events, making the user responsible for our at-least-once semantics. Nevertheless, I would accept this answer.

Comment: You can refer this sample as well: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/graph-proactive-installation/csharp/ProactiveAppInstallation/Bots/ProactiveBot.cs#L75

Answer (score 0):

you can  retrieve the chatId with the following request but it requires the broader Chat.Read.All permission:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/chats?$filter=installedApps/any(a:a/teamsApp/id eq '{teamsAppId}')